# Where is the "Allow Other Amounts?" option?

Tags: contributions, contribution-page, 4.7

If you see the screen shot, from CiviCRM 4.7.22 on Wordpress, isn't there supposed to be an "Allow Other Amounts?" option to check under the "Recurring Donations" option?   According to these instructions, there is supposed to be.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Contribution+Amounts

> Check the Allow Other Amounts? box to allow donors to enter custom amounts for their donation. This will add a field to your contribution page labeled Other Amount. Selecting this option will allow you to set a minimum and maximum amount that can be donated, if desired.

[image: screenshot of "Allow Other Amounts" setting]

Comment: Hi @fdarn, welcome at the CiviCRM department of StackExchange. When you add the version of CiviCRM and the used CMS, you can get betters answers. It is possible that the option you describe was part of an earlier version of CiviCRM, but that it disappeared from the most recent version.  To be sure, try to reproduce it on the demo site http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard .

Answer (score 1):

If you look at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/amount?reset=1&action=update&id=1 you will see the field as per the bottom of this screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I resolved the problem.  I was trying to use a Price Set on the Contribution Page and that is what was removing all fields below "Recurring Donations."  When I deselected that Price Set and just entered the prices manually more fields appeared, including the "Allow other amounts" checkbox.

This was all done on CiviCRM 4.7.22 on Wordpress.